# Appery.io : Setting a local-storage variable via Service Mapping, but Not getting value of local Storage variable in java-script.

Tags: android, javascript

I am getting one problem, please help me to find out the solution.
I couldn't able to tag "Appery.io" in this question, because I am getting message a "Creating a new tag requires at least 1500 reputation points". Someone please create that topic to tag it.

I have one page, and there is one button on it.
On button click event (with Order = 1), I have created one Local storage variable, with blank value (as I will fill value in it from the response of my rest-service).
On button click (with Order = 2) I am calling a web service and in the mapping, I assigned one of the response variable of that service to that local variable.
On Button Click (with Order = 3), I am calling a java script, and in that file, I have written the code to get that local-storage variable (var response = localStorage.getItem('_serviceResponseCode');), when I alert this variable I am not getting anything on it. It is null or undefined. Why ?? Please help me.
I am testing this on android phone as well on windows machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue.. Go to "data" tab. In the event section, Select the Service Name and then choose "Success" event, and write the JS code.